# Moving from one android app to another directly

Tags: android-studio

How can i make my android application use the default applications like mesaaging,etc. I also want to use a bluetooth terminal application from my android application! How do i do this??

Thanks in advance:D

Comment: show something what you have tried or searched for

Comment: Actually i searched a lot for redirecting my app to another app(default SMS app and another installed app called bluetooth terminal) but all i got was how to create a new application for messaging or bluetooth chat etc. similar to this tutorial    https://mobiforge.com/design-development/sms-messaging-android

Comment: I want to do it similar to whatsapp where it guides u different apps for inviting others to whatsapp such as messaging,xender,etc.

Comment: simply call implicit intent you just want to open apps for sharing or invitation purpose ?

Comment: No actually i am electronic engineering student working on an automation project which will be controlled by this android app. I want to send commands to my microcontroller via Bluetooth or SMS  hence i was designing app which could do this. I thought using default or installed apps for connectivity would work . Please let me know if you have any solutions or a better idea. Thank you

Comment: Also please tell me how do i use implicit intent by giving a example